# While applying ON DELETE constraints how to delete entries in child table

Tags: mysql

I want to apply ON DELETE constraint on a existing table. For that i'm using this query:

```
mysql> alter table table_product_varients add constraint fk_test foreign key (product_id) references table_products (product_id) on delete cascade ;
```

And getting this error:

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails.

I understand this error is because i don't have product_id in table_products, but table_product_varients having varients for those product_ids.

I can apply the ON DELETE constraints by setting

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

this will apply ON DELETE constraints but variaent wont get deleted in child table for them there is no product_id in parent table(table_products)

How to apply ON DELETE constraints and also delete the varients in child table for them no parent available?

Comment: AFAIK, that certainly not possible with FK option. You will have to manually delete the orphans and apply constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clean up your table `table_product_varients` for invalid references and then you will be able to add the constraint

```
DELETE FROM table_product_varients
WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM table_products);
```

Answer (score 0):

//THIS WILL DELETE YOUR CHILD WITHOUT PARENTS

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS
WHERE PRODUCT_VARIENT_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_VARIENTS);
```

//AFTER THAT YOU WILL CAN APPLY YOUR FOREIGN KEY

Comment: It should actually be the opposite around `DELETE FROM table_product_varients...` I do not think the parent `table_products` has a fk to its children